# why list[index] with for loop and pass is replacing value inside list

Tags: python

Trying below code:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
for a[1] in a:
    pass
print(a)
```

I am getting output as below:

```
[1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

How can I find out why value of index-1 is changed from 1 to 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the value being iterated to `a[1]` in your loop.

If you try to print your list during iteration it becomes obvious:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8]
for a[1] in a:
    print (a)

#
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

The last value is `8` and it is assigned to `a[1]`, thus `[1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 8]`.

Answer (score 1):

If we use "**for i in a**": In this case a's value will assign one by one to i.

So, in case "**for a[1] in a**": Here, every a's value is assigning to a[1] one by one. Last value is 8, so after completing the loop, only last value which is 8, will assign to a[1].

i.e. a[1] = 8

and **a** will change to **[1,8,2,3,5,8]**